# Output from FINDSTR into a string in batch command

Tags: batch-file, variables, findstr

I would be really grateful for anyone that could save me some time on this.
I have a Windows batch file that I am using to match two different file types with different extensions and write the results out to a file.
It reads through a table of filenames (called matched_filenames.txt) and, for each line in it, tries to locate the filename in two other tables.

I have this code (which works to an extent).

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%z in (%Ourhome%\matched_filenames.txt) do (
rem -------
rem ------- now (for each line), find the photo name in both the list of raw and list of jpg files
rem -------
findstr /C:"%%z" raw_photos_directory.txt >>located_matches.txt
findstr /C:"%%z" jpg_photos_directory.txt >>located_matches.txt
)
```

But it writes separate lines out to the located_matches.txt file.

I would really like to assign the results of the findstr's to variables so that I can then concatenate them and then write the concatenated line as a single line to the file.

Can anyone recommend a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Did you ever stumble over `findstr /G` option? Combined with a `for /f` parsing the outpt of another command you are near.

Comment: No, never tried that. I will research. Thanks

Comment: Can you supply 2 lines of each file, and what you expect in the output file?